# Is anger OK for a husband?

Tags: marriage, shalom-peace, shalom-bayit, emotions

The [Gemara](https://www.themercava.com/app/books/metanav/10883) says that

> וא״ר חִסְדָא תּוּקְפָא בְבֵיתָא כִי קַרְיָא לְשוּמְשְמָא אִידִי וְְאִידִי בְאִיתְּתָא אֲבָל בְגַבְרָא לֵית לָן בָהּ
>
> And Rav Chisda also said: Anger in a house is like a worm in the
> sesame plant. These statements refer to a woman, but in the case
> of a man there is no objection.

How is it that a woman who is angry is like a worm in a sesame but by a man it is ok?

Rambam in [Hilchos Deos 2:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Human_Dispositions.2.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes:

> אמרו חכמים הראשונים: כל הכועס כאילו עובד עבודת כוכבים
>
> The early sages said: Anyone who gets angry, it’s as if he worshipped
> idolatry.

How can we reconcile the two of these?

Comment: The Gemara isn't discussing whether it's ok. It's describing the effect on the household. See Rashi.

Comment: I read in Garden of Peace the exact opposite - the mother's anger is nowhere near as damaging as the fathers. Children instinctively know that mothers have more heart than their fathers, so when a father loses it, it's far more terrifying for the kids.